# Perl substitute from right to left

Tags: java, perl, substitution

I have a string:

```
test1.domain.com.test1.domain.com
```

I want to replace the string domain.com in the right side for result:

```
test1.domain.com.test1
```

When using Perl string replace pattern

```
myString = "test1.domain.com.test1.domain.com";
replacedString = "domain.com";
resultString = null;
Perl5Util perl=new Perl5Util();
resultString =perl.substitute("s/." + replacedString + "//o",myString );
```

However, Perl replaces the string "domain.com" from left to right with the result

```
test1.test1.domain.com
```

Is there any way to change the behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match the end of the string with `$`.

```
perl.substitute("s/." + replacedString + "$//o",myString );
```

You should probably escape that `.` as well, since `.` matches any character.  You might need two backslashes (`\\.`) otherwise the java string will treat it as a special character.  If you don't want to escape the `.` you use the character selection syntax `[.]`.

```
perl.substitute("s/\\." + replacedString + "$//o",myString );
```